# CSV file won't add text when using the append function

Tags: java, file, csv, io

I'm trying to write to a csv file using java and I can't even get the header of the file in. Every time I get a blank text file with no errors. Below is my code

```
 MainfileWriter=new FileWriter(mainTableCSV,true);
 MainfileWriter.append(MAIN_FILE_HEADER.toString());
 MainfileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);
 MainfileWriter.append("test");
```

Comment: do you call `close` and `flush` ?

Comment: call `MainfileWriter.close();` when done writing to file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close or flush after writing, so call `MainfileWriter.close();` when you are done writing the file.

Or you can use `try-with-resources` which will automatically close the file.

```
 try (FileWriter MainfileWriter = new FileWriter(mainTableCSV, true)) {
            MainfileWriter.append(MAIN_FILE_HEADER.toString());
            MainfileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);
            MainfileWriter.append("test");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```